# Add a column results in difference of rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a data frame:

```
        A   B
    0   a   b
    1   c   d
    2   e   f
```

and what I am aiming for is to find the difference between the following rows from `column A`
Like this:

```
        A   B  Ic
    0   a   b  (a-a)
    1   c   d   (a-c)
    2   e   f   (a-e)
```

This is what I tried:

```
df['dA'] = df['A'] - df['A']
```

But it doesn't give me the result I needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select first value by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by index and column name or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) by column name and position and subtract:

```
df['Ic'] = df.loc[0,'A'] - df['A'] 
print (df)
   A  B  Ic
0  4  b   0
1  1  d   3
2  0  f   4
```

---

```
df['Ic'] = df['A'].iat[0] - df['A'] 
print (df)
   A  B  Ic
0  4  b   0
1  1  d   3
2  0  f   4
```

Detail:

```
print (df.loc[0,'A'])
4

print (df['A'].iat[0])
4
```

Comment: Thank you how to get the values in Ic as absolute values

Comment: `df['Ic'] = (df.loc[0,'A'] - df['A']).abs()` should work

Comment: It is weird, I dont understand. Is possible share your data column if not confidental?

Comment: I have posted a new question here in that I showed my data, how it looks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116793/percentage-of-change-of-difference-on-a-dataframe

Comment: I add answer, it seems you need add `abs`