# Percentage of change of difference on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame as following,

```
                     SP        IS
group2      
Control             669303.62   0.00
Test - NonRedeemers 1888366.53  -1219062.91
Test - Redeemers    709095.22   -39791.60
```

I need to calculate the percentage of change of difference, The formulae I wanted to use is `(df['IS']/df.loc['Control'].iat[0])*100`

And I applied it but I need the percentage of absolute values.
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
a = ((df['IS']/df.loc['Control'].iat[0])*100).abs()
print (a)
group2
Control                  0.000000
Test - NonRedeemers    182.138998
Test - Redeemers         5.945224
Name: IS, dtype: float64
```

---

```
a = df['IS'].div(df.loc['Control'].iat[0]).mul(100).abs()
print (a)
group2
Control                  0.000000
Test - NonRedeemers    182.138998
Test - Redeemers         5.945224
Name: IS, dtype: float64
```